# What does sinon's stub.yields do?

Tags: javascript, sinon

The documentation for sinon says stub.yields does this:

> stub.yields([arg1, arg2, ...]) Similar to callsArg.
>
> Causes the stub to **call the first callback it receives** with the
>   provided arguments (if any).
>
> If a method accepts more than one callback, you need to use
>   yieldsRight to call the last callback or callsArg to have the stub
>   invoke other callbacks than the first or last one.

I've read this a few times and can't understand what it is trying to communicate.  I find the bold part to be especially confusing.

What would help me is an explanation that's more detailed than this and an example or two showing how to use `yields` (the documentation does not provide that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the function you are stubbing takes a callback, like an async database request, this allows the stub to fake the results the function would normally pass to your callback.

Probably easier with an example:

```js
// simulated db api
let db = {
  get(query, cb) {
    cb(null, "your results from the query")
  }
}

function runQuery(q) {
  db.get(q, (err, val) => {
    if (err) console.log("error!", err)
    else console.log("value:", val)
  })
}
// call it normally
runQuery("some query")

// stub the DB get method
let stub = sinon.stub(db, 'get');

// fake query results
stub.yields(null, "results from Sinon Stub")

// now stubbed
runQuery("some query")
// assert that `runQuery` did what it should
// given a value of `results from Sinon Stub`
// from db.get

// see how it handles an error:
stub.yields("Some error")

runQuery("some query")
// assert that `runQuery` did what it should
// when db errors with "Some error"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sinon.js/7.3.2/sinon.min.js"></script>
```

This is handy if you have an async function that takes a callback and you want to test it with various results -- for example if you had a database function that you called with a callback:

```
db.get("someVal", (err, val) => {/* do something */}
```

You could simulate various results from the db by yielding different values and run assertions against your code.

Comment: I'm confused by `stub.yields(null, "results from Sinon Stub")`.  I think this is calling `db.get`'s 2nd argument (`(err, val) => {...`) with `null` and `"results from Sinon Stub"`, but what's confusing to me is how it knows to call the 2nd argument as opposed to the first.  What if there were two callbacks in `db.get`'s signature?  Like, what if `db.get`'s signature looked like this: `db.get(q,  (err, val) => {}, b, (err, val) => {})` Does it just call the first callback it finds?

Comment: @DanielKaplan that's why they specify that this "Causes the stub to call the **first** callback".  It passes everything to the first callback. `db.get()` take two arguments — the first is null unless there's an error. This is easily the most common pattern. There are other methods to call the last callback `.yieldsRight()` or `stub.yield()` (without the `s`) to handle mutliple callbacks.